# iPhone Development - TableView Property

Tags: iphone, ios, interface, interface-builder

I am following a tutorial at the following link: http://tempered.mobi/%20

It says:

```
Connect the referencing outlet (of the tableview) to the tableview property.
```

I have a xib file with a table view dragged into it - what is meant by the 'tableview property'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a tableview property in your Objective C code.

You need to have it declared in the header (in the interface as `UITableView* tableView` and then as `@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;`); it should also be synthesized in your `.m` file (`@synthesize tableView`).

This property will then show up in Interface Builder when connecting the UI elements to your class.

This is pretty much UIKit 101, so you might want to start with more basic iPhone tutorials if that's foreign to you.